# Enviar form modal a $.ajax

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Hola gracias por vuestra ayuda. Tengo un formulario modal que obtiene los valores de una consulta Mysql. Pero no consigo pasar los valores del formulario modal a el archivo actualizar datos mediante `$.ajax()`. He buscado mucho, pero soy principiante y no encuentro el modo, agradecería ayuda. 
El código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
 session_start();

  // Controlo si el usuario ya está logueado en el sistema.
  if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    // continuamos en la página.
    include('dbconect.php');
  }else{
    // Si no está logueado lo redireccion a la página de login.
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily");
    header("Location: login.html");
  }


//recibimos las variable por POST 
$fechaD=date("d-m-Y");//convertimos a formato español
$colegio=$_POST['colegio'];
$profesor=$_POST['profesor'];
$actividad=$_POST['actividad'];
$etapa=$_POST['etapa'];
$curso=$_POST['curso'];
$dia=$_POST['dia'];
if ($curso==""){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE colegio='$colegio' AND actividad='$actividad' AND etapa='$etapa' AND activo='S' AND grupo_horario LIKE '$dia' Order by curso, apellidos_alumno";
}else{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE colegio='$colegio' AND actividad='$actividad' AND etapa='$etapa' AND curso='$curso' AND grupo_horario LIKE '$dia' AND activo='S' Order by apellidos_alumno";
}
 if($result=mysqli_query($condb,$sql)){
     mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
         $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    echo  "<h5><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span> ". $fechaD. " - <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-education'></span> ." . $profesor."  - ->  " . $actividad ."- -> Curso :" . $row['curso'] ."&ordm;.</h5>";
        echo"<div class='row' style='background-color: #f3f3f3'><h6>
            <div class='col-xs-4'>Apellidos</div>
            <div class='col-xs-2'>Nombre</div>
            <div class='col-xs-3'>Horario</span></div>
            <div class='col-xs-1'>+ Falta</div>
            <div class='col-xs-1'>Envio mail</div>     
         </h6></div>";
    $num=1;
    //mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);

    do {
        //Esto es para los encabezados de grupo por Curso
        $grupoant=$curso;
        $curso=$row['curso'];
             if($grupoant != $curso){
                echo"<div class='row well-sm'><h3> * ".$curso ." &ordm; .- Curso </h3></div>";
                $num=1;
             }
             //convierte la fecha a formato europeo
    $Fnac = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['fnac']));
        $IdAlu=$row['IdAlumno'];
echo"<div class='modal fade' id='modalForm".$IdAlu."' role='dialog'>
    <div class='modal-dialog'>
        <div class='modal-content'>

            <div class='modal-header'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>
                    <span aria-hidden='true'>×</span>
                    <span class='sr-only'>Cerrar</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>".$IdAlu."<img src='images/alumnos/".$IdAlu.".jpg' class='media-object' width='94' height='110' hspace='10' align='left'  /><br>".utf8_encode($row['apellidos_alumno']).", ". utf8_encode($row['nombre_alumno']) ." - Curso: ".$row['curso'].$row['letra']. "</h4><br>Fecha nac: ".$row['fnac']."


            </div>";
           //Esto es para el formulario modal de los datos del alumno

        echo" <div class='modal-body'>
                <p class='statusMsg'></p>
                <form role='form'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputIdAlumno' name='inputIdAlumno' value='".$row['IdAlumno']."'/>
                        <label for='nombre_padre'>Padre/madre: ".$row['nombre_padre']."</label>
                        <label for='tfno'>.- Tfnos: ".$row['telefonos']." </label> <br>
                        <label for='inputMail'>e-mail: ".$row['mail_aviso']."</label>
                </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='inputActivo'>En Activo:</label>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputActivo'  name='inputActivo'  value='".$row['activo']."' readonly/>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='inputHorario'>Horario:</label>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputhorario' name='inputhorario' placeholder='' value='".$row['grupo_horario']."' readonly/>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='inputLicencia'>Licencia:</label>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputLicencia' name='inputLicencia' placeholder='' value='".$row['licencia']."'/>
                        <label for='inputCinturon'>Cinturón:</label>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputCinturon' name='inputCinturon' placeholder='' value='".$row['cinturon']."'/>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='inputDNI'>DNI-alumno:</label>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputDNI'  name='inputDNI' placeholder='' value='".$row['dni_alumno']."'/>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='inputFNAC'>Fecha nacimiento:</label>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputFNAC' name='inputFNAC' placeholder='' value='".$Fnac."'/>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='inputObs1'>Observaciones 1 :</label>
                        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='inputObs1' name='inputObs1' value='".$row['observaciones_alumno1']."' readonly/>
                    </div>
                    <div class='form-group'>
                        <label for='inputObs2'>Observaciones 2 :</label>
                        <textarea class='form-control' id='inputObs2' name='inputObs2' placeholder='Anota alguna Observación de este alumno' >".$row['observaciones_alumno2']."</textarea>
                    </div>

            </div>

            <div id='respuesta'></div>
            <div class='modal-footer'>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cerrar</button>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary submitBtn' onclick='submitContactForm()'>Guardar cambios</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>";
//////////////////////////////////////////////
    echo"<div class='row row-padded'><h6>
            <div class='col-xs-4'>  
            <a href='#' role='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalForm".$IdAlu."' id='modalF'  >
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></a> " . $num++." - " .utf8_encode($row['apellidos_alumno']) . "</div>
            <div class='col-xs-2 color-class'>" . utf8_encode($row['nombre_alumno']) . "</div>
            <div class='col-xs-3 color-class'><span class='text-danger'>". $row['grupo_horario'] . "</span></div>
            <div class='col-xs-1 color-class'><a href=\"falta_asistencia.php?Idalumno=".$row['IdAlumno']. "&horario=". $row['grupo_horario']. "&actividad=". $row['actividad']."&profesor=". $profesor." \"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Hilt</a>--<a href=\"ver_ausencia.php?Idalumno=".$row['IdAlumno']." \"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></a></div>
            <div class='col-xs-1 color-class'><a href=\"envio_mail.php?Idalumno=".$row['IdAlumno']." \"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></span></a></div>       
         </h6></div>";

        } while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
        //Fin while
     // <div class='col-xs-1'><a href=\"falta_asistencia.php?Idalumno=".$row['IdAlumno']." \" class='btn btn-default btn-sm'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Hilt</a></div>

    }//Fin if consulta
    else{
        print "Error en la consulta";

    }

    //Ahora script para envío de datos a Mysql con las modificaciones   
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitContactForm(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'actualiza_alumno.php',
            data: $("#form").serialize,
            success: function(response) {
            $('#respuesta').html(response);
            }
        });

}
    </script>
```

Comment: que error te sale?

Comment: Solo coge los parametros del primer formulario que lee el select y guarda siempre los valores del primer registro.